# load entire content of one ressource bundle(message.properties ) using ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This is the action class which is being used for getting the data from properties:

```
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

    public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Autowired
        private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

        public String execute() {
            try {
                System.out.println(messageSource.toString());
                String message = messageSource.getMessage("test.prop", null,
                        "Default", null);

                System.out.println(message);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                addActionError(e.getMessage());
                return INPUT;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }

    }
```

Below is my application context which contains the message resource configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basenames">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>file:/properties/messages</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>

        <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>
```

message.properties contains data in the form of key and value pair.

```
    test.prop=stack overflow.
    test.prop1=test1
    test.prop2=asdf
```

Here instead of getting single property (i.e. test.prop) which is coming in message variable, I want to get complete content of message.properties.

How can we do that? Can any one help?

Comment: I have gone through below link  where they have mentioned customization of PropertiesPersistor  but its not working :                                             http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/42714-get-all-content-from-resourcebundlemessagesource